# Avoiding massive garbage collection

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection

This is a question to get a general idea how to avoid this situation. I have potentially millions of things, each with a few floats. I have to iterate through all of them, and inside the loop I have to do some calculations.

It is something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    var num1 = thing[i].x * something;
    var num2 = thing[i].y * somethingElse;
    buffer.push(num1);
    buffer.push(num2);
    var num3 = thing[i].z * something;
    var num4 = thing[i].w * somethingElse;
    buffer2.push(num3);
    buffer2.push(num4);
}
```

I find that my memory usage explodes into the hundreds of megabytes and the browser crashes. As you can see, there is nothing hard about what I need to do, but I just need to do it on A LOT of things. I have found that the browser correctly garbage collects the temporary floats and my memory usage drops quickly, but that is assuming the browser doesn't crash first.

Any ideas how I could get the browser to garbage collect periodically (or some similar solution) so I don't end up with a huge gob of memory that crashes the browser?

Comment: My hunch is that this is more about how much memory you are holding onto, and not memory that is waiting to be garbage collected.  You are persisting two buffers with millions of elements each.  So as long as you keep those around you need memory for them.  I believe the garbage collector runs "as needed", but it can't clean up what isn't garbage.

Comment: that was my initial guess too, but when i profiled my memory, virtually all of it was garbage collected when the browser didnt crash.

Comment: sorry, i was wrong about that. there is some connection to how big my arrays are getting. i can easily create 50mil arrays with floats in them, so im not sure why i cant do the same in my example. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing it in portions inside a function scope, have not tried this particular case, but pretty sure variables are garbage collected once they are out of scope:

```
function doPortion(nFrom, nTo) {
    for (var i = nFrom; i < nTo; i++) {
        var num1 = thing[i].x * something;
        var num2 = thing[i].y * somethingElse;
        buffer.push(num1);
        buffer.push(num2);
        var num3 = thing[i].z * something;
        var num4 = thing[i].w * somethingElse;
        buffer2.push(num3);
        buffer2.push(num4);
    }
}

var nStep = 1000;
for (var n=0; n<10000000-nStep; n += nStep) {
    doPortion(n, n+nStep);
}
```

Comment: this is close enough to what ended up working. i ended up being able to split things among several arrays, but the idea of splitting the work up allows chrome to garbage collect in between and thus not crash. thanks for the idea!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have logic witch is repeatable, do it dynamically... where you create needed value when it's really needed:

kind of: http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/qdxLv/2/

```
var something = 10, somethingElse = 20;
function buffer(i){
    var num1 = thing(i).x * something;
    var num2 = thing(i).y * somethingElse;
    return [num1, num2];
}

function thing(i){
    return {x: i*10,y:i*1.5};
}

//get needed value
buffer(20);
alert(buffer(20))
```

Comment: I think this is the best bet. Functions create their own scopes which are easy to cleanup. So repeatedly invoking a function that only operates on a little bit of data should allow the garbage collector to work it's magic.

Answer (score 0):

reduce this case by twice memeroy consumption, just link second buffer to first;

```
var buffer = [];
var buffer2 = buffer;
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    var num1 = thing[i].x * something;
    var num2 = thing[i].y * somethingElse;
    buffer.push(num1);
    buffer.push(num2);
}
```

updating first buffer you are updating second as well

Comment: "updating first buffer you are updating second as well" No... you are updating the same buffer, that happens to be referenced by two variables.

Comment: Given that the example contains `something` and `somethingElse` it's fair to say this is a contrived example.  And if he needs two buffers for some reason, your solution won't provide that.

Comment: maybe, but looking carefully, buffer and buffer2 been pushed 100% same stuff, in that case do not forget that if you create some other equals to another they are linked.

Comment: ill update my example. @AlexWayne is right that i do need two buffers and the contents arent the same.